# How to shut down a Jersey generated Jetty webserver in case createServer() throws a ProcessingException?

Tags: java, jersey, jetty

I use [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) to create a [Jetty](https://eclipse.org/jetty/) webserver like this:

```
ResourceConfig context = new ResourceConfig();
...
URI baseUri = ...
Server server = JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(baseUri, context);
```

If the port the Jetty server attempts to bind to is taken, the `createServer()` method throws a `ProcessingException`. However, the server stays alive in some kind of limbo with several threads running, but (obviously) without functioning.

Since the `ProcessingException` was thrown during the `createServer()` call, my `server` variable is never set, and I thus have no way to access the server just created in order to call the `stop()` method on it.

How do I shut it down the broken server in a clean way? I do not want to kill the entire application using `System.exit()`.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, file it at both the Jersey and Jetty bug trackers.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Alright. I reported it here for now (since `JettyHttpContainerFactory` belongs to Jersey): https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2875